# Is there any option to count the tags loading?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I would like to know the number of times each tag is being load every day.
Did someone came up with a reporting solution?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge GTM does not report how often a tag has been triggered (as a few other tag management solutions do indeed do).  However you could simply attach tracking pixels from your own server to each rule/trigger; they would appear in your server logfile and you would be able to count how often each rule has been triggered (which would correspond to the number of time a tag attached to that trigger has been loaded). A rather homegrown solution, but it might serve your needs.